# how to match two animation of different object and copy view one object another in android

Tags: android, animation

I am doing little  animation in my project.

I am new to android I didn't know much Api in android please
help me do small application.

**My image here**

[image]

In my app two object are there one rectangle and other circle, rectangle moving diagonally down towards circle and circle moving upward and copy rectangle and set visibility gone for both object.
for that am using xml translator to move object

xml file down to left

>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:duration="5000"
           android:fromYDelta="0%p"
           android:toXDelta="2%p"
          android:toYDelta="-40%p" />
```

and calling xml using Java

> 

```
private void hideView(final View view)
{
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down_to_up);
    //use this to make it longer:  animation.setDuration(1000);

    animation.setDuration(2500);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

calling first object

```
            Animation animation1=new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 130.0f);
            animation1.setDuration(2000);
            object1.startAnimation(animation1);
```

>
        calling second object
                 hideView(object2);

Comment: you forgot the link of the image

Comment: how to do that please let me konw

Comment: put this at bottom -- > [1]:linkoftheimage

Comment: To put image at least 10 reputation is required

Comment: then remove the "!" and post it like a url

Comment: I attached image please check and let me know I can implement